# Matlab: How to show sigma and mu on normal curve

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting a normal curve by using `y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma);` in Matlab.
This draws for me a normal curve. But, I need additional information to be shown on the curve, like having vertical lines on the curve to show the mu and the sigma. Similar to this one:
[image]

Is there any Matlab function to draw such vertical lines on the curve?

Thanks,
Aida

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just `plot`-ting 3 lines (or using `line`)?

Comment: It works and draws the line. However, I need the sigma and mu to be written on x-axis where the vertical line intersects it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no built-in function for this, but we can do it easily by the hands:

Create normal curve and plot it:

```
x = -2:0.05:2;
mu = 0; sigma = 0.5;
y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
plot(x,y)
```

Add lines for sigmas:

```
hold on;
plot( [mu - sigma mu - sigma],[0 max(y)],'--')
plot( [mu + sigma mu + sigma],[0 max(y)],'--')
```

You can change it to any sigma you need (2sigma 3sigma).
How to add the text? This way:

```
text(0.1,-0.05,'mu + sigma');
```

or if you want it look really beautiful:

```
text(-0.65,-0.05,'\mu - \sigma')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to draw lines in Matlab is probably using simply `plot`. The following code segment draws a line from [x1, y1] to [x2, y2]:

```
plot([x1,y1], [x2,y2], plotoptions)
```

To make sure that this line is also visible on your current figure use `hold on`. This results in a code like the following:

```
y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma)
figure(1)
    hold on
    plot(x,y) % Your normal distribution
    plot([mu,startY], [mu, stopY], plotoptions) % Plot the line at position mu.
                                                % The startY and stopY indicate the bottom and top of your graph.
    hold off
```

The Mathworks documentation page of plot can be a great reference, with a lot of examples and different plot options. For example how to make a dashed or colored line:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot%20line